# How to check if field allow multiple values using core service

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Using core service how can we check if a field allow multiple values, below is the code I'm using to get the type of field:-

```
SchemaFieldsData fields = client.ReadSchemaFields(schemaTCMURI, true, new ReadOptions());

                foreach (var field in fields.MetadataFields)
                {
                    if (field is SingleLineTextFieldDefinitionData)
                    {
                        // some code
                    }
                    else if (field is MultiLineTextFieldDefinitionData)
                    {
                // this will check only if field is multiline not multi valued                        }
```

}

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the `MinOccurs` and `MaxOccurs` properties. If `MinOccurs` is 0 the field is optional, otherwise it's mandatory. If `MaxOccurs` is 1, the field is single-value. Otherwise it's multi-value.

Answer (score 3):

According to Core Service documentation, you can check for field. MaxOccurs

- MaxOccurs == 1 means single valued field
- MaxOccurs == - 1 means means valued field